# Can I find a way to remove some system data from storage?

Tags: debian, storage

[image: 30.9GB/1.1GB]

I really don't know what happened but everytime I powerwash (factory reset) it goes back to its limit. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Could you please tell precisely what system you are running on what sort of hardware ? How you obtained the image you posted (what command did you run ? from where ?) And additionally in what should consist the "factory reset"

Comment: I am using a Google Chrome OS with the Version 104.0.5112.57 (Official Build) beta (64-bit). My settings (I think I used the command curl https://chrx.org/ | sudo tar xzfC - /usr/local && chrx in chrosh shell) and I kinda don't understant the last question. @MC68020